# Could not GET 'url' Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed in Android Studio when I run gradle build

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is the full error that I got

`Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed`

How to fix this error